# Typescript class force Type properties implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, implements

Given a Type:

```
type TestType = {
  a?: string;
  b?: number;
  c?: boolean;
};
```

I want to create a class that implements `TestType` with all its properties names where the types could be different.

*If not, raise an error.*

I've tried with `Pick`, `Required`, etc. without success.

Example (error):

```
/* Error, not all TestType properties are implemented */
class TestClass implements TestType {}
```

Example (correct):

```
class TestClass implemenets TestType {
  a?: boolean;   // Different type
  b?: number;    // Same type
  c?: string;    // Different type
}
```

Can this be achieved with Typescript?

Thanks!

Comment: If you say `TestClass` is an implementation (or child or whatever) of `TestType` then the expectation is that `TestClass` can be used wherever `TestType` is used. Yet you are breaking that relationship. Are you sure this is exactly what you want? Is this possible [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

We can make a utility `type` called `ToAny` for this:

```
type ToAny<T> = {[K in keyof T]: any}
```

Usage:

```
class TestClass implements ToAny<TestType> {}

class TestClass2 implements ToAny<TestType> {
  a?: boolean;   // Different type
  b?: number;    // Same type
  c?: string;    // Different type
}
```